# How to empty collection in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In my code i am inserting a collection dynamically and this collation have default

```
_id:ObjectId("5ed0d4d3fec27620043ee59d")
__v:0
```

I think this is default inserted in mongodb.Actully i no need like this si i am trying to remove these two _id and __:0 but not working.

Below my code:

```
   var NewModel = require(path.resolve('./models/newmodelschema.model.js'))(collectionName);
   NewModel.create({}, function(err, doc) { 
                NewModel.remove({_id:'',__v:0}, function(err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Model empty");
                    }
                }); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable _id and _v by using options { _id: false, versionKey: false }, while creating schema.

Example:

1. create schema like below

```
    const NewModel = new mongoose.Schema({
      "name": { type: string}
    }, { _id: false, versionKey: false });
```

2. Now insert a data,

```
NewModel.create({ "name": "foo"}, function(err, doc){
console.log("data ", doc);
});
```

It should print,

```
data { "name": "foo" }
```

without _id and __v

Edit 2:
You can't remove _id unless it's a subdocument

PS: I would recommend to keep this both, to know about these fields please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field and https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey

Comment: { _id: false, versionKey: false } this is not working..{  versionKey: false } is only working

Comment: You have any solution?

Comment: You can't remove _id, _id: false works only for subdocument.